# Form validation? make textbox border green/red depending on conditions

Tags: javascript

How do i make it so the border of the phone number box is green when it follows the format: 123 456 7890 (3 digits, space, 3 digits, space, 4 digits) and red if it does not?

additionally, how do i make it so the product id/product info text box border is green when RW100, RW101, RW102, RW103, RW200, RW201, RW202, or RW203 are entered and red when not?

thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/MangoMelody_/yfv8rcx2/5/

```
<script>
//product id validation
function idCheck() {
  var prodNameBox = document.getElementById("prodname");
  var prodname = prodNameBox.innerText;
  if (prodname === 'RW100' || prodname === 'RW101' || prodname === 'RW102' || prodname === 'RW103' || prodname === 'RW200' || prodname === 'RW201' || prodname === 'RW202' || prodname === 'RW203') {
    prodNameBox.style.borderColor = "green";
  } else {
    prodNameBox.style.borderColor = "red";
  }
}

// phone number validation
function phoneNumber() {
  var phonenoBox = document.getElementById("phoneno");
  var phoneno = phonenoBox.value;

  if ((phoneno.value.match("^[1-9]\d{2}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}"))) {
    phonenoBox.style.borderColor = "green";
  } else {
    phonenoBox.style.borderColor = "red";

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, your submit button should call the check functions, currently it only shows the alert box. Also it's not clear from your question what exactly is not working? (after you call your correct functions).

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation